# How do I display an ArrayList of StrokeTransition one by one in JavaFX?

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

I want to create a graph and animate chosen lines 'one-by-one'.

Basically: I want ArrayList 'trans' play all elements one after another.

```
int a = 0;
ArrayList<Line> nodeline = new ArrayList<Line>();
ArrayList<StrokeTransition> trans = new ArrayList<StrokeTransition>();
ArrayList<Double> lineaxisx = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> lineaxisy = new ArrayList<Double>();

for(int i = 0; i < dainput.size(); i += 3) {

    lineaxisx.add((double)axisx.get(dainput.get(i)));
    lineaxisx.add((double)axisx.get(dainput.get(i+1)));
    lineaxisy.add((double)axisy.get(dainput.get(i)));
    lineaxisy.add((double)axisy.get(dainput.get(i+1)));

    nodeline.add(new Line(axisx.get(dainput.get(i)),axisy.get(dainput.get(i)),axisx.get(dainput.get(i+1)),axisy.get((dainput.get(i+1)))));
    nodeline.get(a).setStroke(Color.CYAN);

    for(int j = 0; j < daiout.size(); j += 3){
        if(daiout.get(j) == dainput.get(i) && daiout.get(j+1) == dainput.get(i + 1) && daiout.get(j + 2) == dainput.get(i + 2)){
            trans.add(new StrokeTransition(Duration.millis(10000), nodeline.get(a), Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE));
        }
    }

    root.getChildren().addAll(nodeline.get(a));
    a++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`SequentialTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html) is made exactly for this. All you need is

```
SequentialTransition animation = new SequentialTransition() ;
animation.getChildren().addAll(trans);
animation.play();
```